# Flutterr Horizontal ListViewBuilder in column that inside SingleChildeScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I have to display horizontal ListView.Builder in Column that is child of SingleChildScrollView. ListView.Builder have Column child, that expanded to size of his content.

And ofcourse i get error that i can't do this because of infinity expansion. How i can fix it ? I tried to wrap ListView.builder with Expanded and i can't user SizedBox with fixed size.

this is my childe tree

[image]

and this is my child tree for widget that i put inside ListView.builderr

[image]

Comment: try shrinkWrap: true inside a ListView.builder.

Answer (score -1):

Use another `SingleChildScrollView` with `Axis.horizontal,`

```dart
Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Row(
            children: List.generate(
                44,
                (index) => Row(
                      children: [Text("item $index")],
                    )),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

You might like using [`CustomScrollView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html)

Comment: I can't use SizedBox with fixed height

Comment: @GDTyka Can you comment your feedback on update answer?